# Kubernetes Docker AUFS DIFF directory growing

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running Kubernetes v1.2.3.

On both of my minions my /mnt/ephemeral/docker/aufs/diff directory is quite large. Seems to be files for pods that do not even exist anymore.

[image: AUFS DIFF Directory]

How can I clean this directory up?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: If those are the docker images, those should be handled by the [garbage collector](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/garbage-collection/). You can adjust its free space threshold.

Comment: They are not the docker images. They are AUFS layers. They don't seem to be cleaning themselves up.

Comment: The default threshold is really high -- 80% or 90% iirc. Are you actually running out of space or just worried you would?

Comment: Just ran out of space - to answer that question from two years ago.